# How to close Nested Virtualization popup for emulator while running automation test

Tags: android, docker, appium, selenoid

Is there any way to close the Nested Virtualization popup which is shown in the center of the screen? I am running an Automation test using Appium, Ruby, and Selenoid.

When I run a test on the android device and it starts the container and also starts the emulator but it displays a popup on the center of the screen.

Is there any way I can close this popup?

Note: I don't have any access to this popup, I think it is an OS-level (Linux) popup. I cannot click on this popup

Refer screenshot [image]

Comment: How abut just choosing "Never show this again" ?

Comment: @Ukarsh Dixit I don't have any access to this popup, I think it is an OS-level (Linux) popup. I cannot click on this popup

Comment: @vania-pooh any input on this?

Comment: See https://github.com/aerokube/images/commit/c1732f1bb199c924c7dfa54ff077f6186b30e30f#diff-e46d30218f60a2119f74179e0de706d76c655e36dadb0dd7aab09bb80dc9539c

Comment: @vania-pooh - I am new to docker but it seems like I have to create a new image with this configuration. I tried passing 'showNestedWarning=false' in capabilities but it didn't work and this is OS-level dialog box so I don't think setting capabilities will work.

Comment: Should just rebuild an image with Android using source code above.